# Technical preview download for developers

Tags: windows-10-preview

I used to run the technical preview on my device so I could bring out a Windows 10 application when the upgrade becomes available to everyone.

Recently my hard-drive died so I replaced it. Unfortunately Microsoft decided to stop the [insider program](https://insider.windows.com/) since they are close to an accentual release at the 29th.

As developer I want to be able to finish my application before then so I can release it on launch. Is there any way developers can still get the ISO file and a working key?

Comment: Microsoft will continue the Insider Preview after July 29th, until then, even if you had an .ISO and a key, you wouldn't be able to activate the installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Windows 10 RTM Build 10240 was recently released. People have [created ISOs](http://microsoft-news.com/download-windows-10-rtm-build-10240-iso/) from the ESD file from Windows Update. There is a key included in the article. You can download that and install it.

You can continue to run Insider Preview builds after the release. If you want a final version, you would need to upgrade from an existing license or buy one.

Comment: Thanks! Would my 8.1 license qualify?

Comment: If it is genuine, yes. Have you received the update and gotten an icon in the taskbar telling you to reserve Windows 10?

Comment: @Alagaros - The license qualifications have not changed.  You just can't do a clean installation, because you won't be able to activate the installation, until they issue new Technical Preview keys and continue the Insider Program.

Comment: Its genuine, I have not seen the icon yet but that's because I was running on the preview ever since it came out.

Comment: @Alagaros - Sounds like you don't have the required update.  There is an existing question, with an answer, with several possible solutions to the "Upgrade to Windows 10" icon not being visible.

Comment: Preview of which version? It has to be an actual license of 7 or 8.1 to upgrade to Windows 10 when it is released.

Comment: The key provided will allow you to install the 10240 build, you just can't activate the installation, until Microsoft continues with the Technical Preview program.